# tableview error in xcode 5 using objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i wrote a program to display the table in iPad.my program is below:

```
@implementation ViewController

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:@"cell"];


    cell.textLabel.text=@"this is a cell";

    return cell;
}
```

no issuses.but when i am running my program,thread will display like below:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Thread 1:signal SIGBABRT

Comment: Why don't you read some documentation/tutorials/examples first?
The code you provide as an example, just screams out loud: "Hey, I'm here! I didn't read any docs and just trying out to shoot myself in a foot!"

Comment: @eagle.dan.1349 Maybe you should learn to put more productive comments. `Madhu M` I have removed the `xcode` tag because this doesn't have anything to do with `xcode` itself, please be careful when using this tag in the future. Please could you also share the stacktrace and have you tried to add an exception breakpoint? The app doesn't crash on `main` like it is showing the reason it gets to there is because you aren't catching the exception that is being thrown.

Comment: @Popeye If I understand correctly, StackOverflow is a wrong place to go and ask a question "why it blew whole my leg?" before RTFM. The code I see in example, just breaks iOS coding standarts/guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

`TableViewCell` `allocation` issue.If cells available we need to reuse that else we need to create one.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        static NSString * identifier = @"cellIdentifier";
//Cell reusing..
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (!cell)
        {
// Cell creation
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        }
    cell.textLabel.text=@"this is a cell";
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: i tried this.but i got same error as i mentioned in my question

Comment: SIGABRT is gerneral crash ,can u update with full error report that displayed in your console

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0xba23640> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key textLabel.'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: r u using custom cell or basic cell.Use basic cell and remove all unnecessary outlets.or try with a new tableView

Answer (score 0):

Need a stack trace to really know, but there's a very good chance your app is getting ejected for memory issues. You should be using reuseable cells inside your tableView to minimize the chance of that happening.

You need to assign a cell identifier for your prototype cells and then you can call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` and pass in that identifier inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That way, when cells are scrolled offscreen they are reused for the upcoming cells. You will likely see big improvements in performance and scrolling speed. If that doesn't fix the issue, there's some other critical issues in your app that you can diagnose using Instruments.

Comment: If i put this:
  UITableViewCell *cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:@"cell"];  i got error like this:
use of undeclared identifier:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier

Comment: That's because you need to register the identifier. Also it should be, `YourCellSubclass *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReuseableCellWithIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier"`]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the problem is that you are not following guidelines that Apple provides.

Always creatie new cell in is bad practice.
Keep cells in array in your view controller is bad practice.
Ignore documentation is even worse.

Try this code:

```
@implementation ViewController

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString* reuseIdentifier = @"cell";
   UITableViewCell *cell= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   if (!cell)
   {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefaultreuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
   }
   cell.textLabel.text=@"this is a cell";

return cell;
```

}

[And don't forget to read documentation](http://bit.ly/1sG7Dw5)